# Why id doesn't match /\*{2}(.*)\*/

Tags: java, regex

I want to select the following text with my regex `/*{2}(.*)*/`

```
 /**
 * <p>
 * and writes file to {@link #writeToFile(String, java.util.Map) writeToFile} \\n
 * ddddddddddddd
 * </p>
 * <p>bla bla</p>
 *
 * and get from class.
 *
 * @param filePath
 * @param classes
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
```

But it does't match. I don't know what I am doing wrong . That is how I read, find `\` followed my two instance of `*` and then match to anything until find `*` followed by `/`.

But it only matches to the `/**` everything else is ignored.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `*` by putting a `\` in front of it. When it's unescaped, it'll be interpreted as the arbitrary repetition quantifier as used in your pattern: `(.*)`

After being escaped, your pattern should look like this, then:

```
/\*{2}(.*)\*/
```

If your language requires you to escape backslashes in strings, make sure to double-escape them. In Java, the pattern `\\*` denotes the regular expression `\*`, which matches a `*` literal.

---

Note that to parse this comment syntax, most languages will stop at the first `*/`, which is why it would probably be better to make the `*` quantifier [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) by appending a `?` to it:

```
/\*{2}(.*?)\*/
```

That way, if you run the regex against e.g. `/** foo bar */ */`, only `foo bar` will be matched (excluding the following `*/`, as would be the case with a [greedy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)).

Comment: Look at the question title, that's what OP already has :) There's some confusion going on here...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The question was edited after my reply.

Comment: Not the title, I saw the question in pristine state.

Comment: @user3054608 Did you make sure to double-escape your escape sequences for Java strings?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Oh, that's true. My bad, I focused on the (unedited) question.

Comment: Hi Guys, sorry for the confusion but the title of the question has the right regex. The text editor somehow modified my regex.

Comment: @user3054608 Have you tried applying the double-escaping yet?

Comment: OP should really have posted an actual code snippet. This way we are all talking past each other.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the [modifier (?s)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for making the dot match all characters, including line breaks.

as a Java string:

```
String regex = "(?s)/\\*{2}(.*?)\\*/";
```

Comment: @RyanCarlson Learned a lot [on this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), [and here](http://www.rexegg.com/), [and there](http://regex.info/), and on SO of course :)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that **.** (Point) means "any character except newline".
So this one here would be your solution:

```
/[\*]{2}(.*?\n)* \*/
```

If you need a group to catch out the Informations of that Block it would look like this:

```
/[\*]{2}((?:.*?\n)*) \*/
```

Comment: @user3054608 This expression can become terribly inefficient and lead to [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Also, the brackets are superfluous. Specifying `Pattern.DOTALL` to allow the dot (`.`) to also match newlines would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rassmussen and Marius Schulz are both correct. You need to double escape all `*` like `\\*`, and the `.` doesn't match newline characters, e.g. `\n`, `\r`.

Here is a string that, when implemented as a regex, will match any javadoc comment on any OS:

```java
"/\\*\\*(?:.|\r?\n)*?\\*/"
```

tested at http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html

Explaination:

- `/` matches the literal character `\`.
- `\\*` matches the literal character `*`.
- `(?:.|\r?\n)` is a non-capturing group.

  - `(?:` starts the non-capturing group.
  - `.` matches any character except newline characters.
  - `|` is the equivalent of an "or".
  - **`\r?\n` matches a newline on any operating system. on UNIX-based OSs, `\n` is a newline, but on Windows, newlines are `\r\n`. `?` makes the previous item optional, so `\r?\n` will match both `\n` *and* `\r\n`. This makes the regex work on any OS.**
  - `)` ends the non-capturing group.
- `*?` repeats the previous item, `(?:.|\r?\n)`, zero or more times, as few times as possible.
- `\\*` matches the literal character `*`.
- `/` matches the literal character `\`.

Depending on how you are implementing the regex, you can also use `Pattern`'s `DOTALL` flag with the regex

```java
/\*\*.*?\*/
```

for example:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\*\\*.*?\\*/", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

which uses the [`public static Pattern compile(String regex, int flags)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method with the [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan, finally I build something of my own which selects the comments ((/\*).*\n)((.*\n).*)* tested on http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html thanks for telling me this website its wonderful. I can practice my regex there.

Comment: @Ashish You are very welcome! If one of the answers here satisfactorily answers your question, you should click the check mark next to it. Go here for more information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238586